# Javascript Chart Library that support loading from csv/xml/json

Tags: javascript, charts

I search some free js charting library (bar,line,pie) that works standalone (no JQuery, MooTools, Prototype, etc) with feature support loading data from file (csv/xml/json, csv preffered).

Something like gRaphael is nice but it doesn't support loading data from external file

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The [D3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) library has no external dependencies (though it does require a modern browser with SVG support) and includes [a set of functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests) for loading data from external sources, including CSV, XML, and JSON files.

It's not quite as out-of-the-box as some of the other options, but after a reasonable learning curve you can do just about anything any of the other Javascript libraries can do.

Answer (score 6):

This question is old but since it continues to pop up in search results, I hope others who are having this need can find the following JS library as useful as I find it.

http://dygraphs.com/

It supports loading from CSVs and others. Its very fast with lots of data points.

Answer (score 0):

A js chart library, unlimited free commercial use, supports XML and the above mentioned chart types: http://mindfusion.eu/free-js-chart.html